# Functional test - Cookies not updating

Tags: php, symfony, testing, symfony6

I have a "Remember my email" checkbox on my login form which when ticked off and login is successful, creates a cookie "loginData" to remember the user email (obviously). Although, when unchecked and login is successful, the authenticator (custom authenticator) looks for this "loginData" cookie and if finds any, deletes it. **Works fine on my website** (tested with the dev tools on Chrome), not during functional testing.

Here is my test function (*sorry for the name of the function*):

```
public function testRememberEmailCheckboxNotCheckedCookiePreExistent(): void
{
    $client = static::createClient();
    
    $cookie = new Cookie('loginData', 'chocolate', strtotime('+1 year'));
    $client->getCookieJar()->set( $cookie );

    $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/login');

    $button = $crawler->selectButton('Login');
    $form = $button->form();

    $form['_remember_my_email']->untick();

    $client->submit($form, [
        '_username' => $email,      //defined before
        '_password' => $password    //defined before
    ]);

    $this->assertResponseRedirects("/");

    $client->followRedirect();

    $this->assertResponseStatusCodeSame(Response::HTTP_OK);

    $this->assertBrowserNotHasCookie('loginData'); //Failed asserting that the Browser does not have cookie "loginData"

}
```

Any solutions/suggestions will be very much appreciated (*it's driving me insane*) :D

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem. Turns out that the cookie is not actually deleted from the header of the response when using `$response->headers->clearCookie('loginData')` in the authenticator, it just has an empty value.

**Fix:**

```
public function testRememberEmailCheckboxNotCheckedCookiePreExistent(): void
{
    $client = static::createClient();
        
    $cookie = new Cookie('loginData', 'chocolate', strtotime('+1 year'));
    $client->getCookieJar()->set( $cookie );

    $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/login');

    $button = $crawler->selectButton('Login');
    $form = $button->form();

    $form['_remember_my_email']->untick();

    $client->submit($form, [
        '_username' => $email, 
        '_password' => $password,
    ]);
        
    $this->assertResponseCookieValueSame('loginData', '');

}
```